# MVVM Light RelayCommand.CanExecute. Can I opt out of disabling UI?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I have a windows phone 8 silverlight application and I'm using MVVM Light RelayCommands bound to the items of a LongListSelector.

The RelayCommands are declared like this

```
    private RelayCommand _goToDetailsCommand;
    public RelayCommand GoToDetailsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _goToDetailsCommand ?? (_goToDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteGoToDetailsCommand, () => !SessionVM.IsLoading));
        }
    }
```

My problem is that according to the CanExecute of the RelayCommands the UI is Disabled or Enabled (which is the default behavior).
Can I opt out of that behavior and still use the CanExecute of the RelayCommand??

Comment: Why would you use it otherwise?

Comment: @Will The reasons I want to get rid of the effect is two fold. 1) according to the design of the app the items should never appear disabled.
2) Sometimes it causes a LayoutCycleException

Comment: Okay, but that's the only (normal) use of `CanExecute`.  What are you using it for?  See, for me, I'd just `x => true` that sucker so it's always true, then use whatever would normally go in there elsewhere.  Sounds like you're wanting to leave it so you can use it elsewhere, but not in the UI.  It don't make no sense.

Comment: @Will At the moment that's pretty much what I'm doing, in the commands where the problem arrises. However everywhere else in my application i use the CanExecute so I wanted to have more consistent code.

Comment: So... you want a helmet because you're uniformly hitting things with your hammer, including your head?  Hit the nails with the hammer, and when you don't need to hit something, don't worry about an inconsistent use of your tool.  Use the tools the way they were designed.

Comment: @Will That's a pretty graphic way of putting it but yes :) .